# Getting undefined results in Node Mysql (Discrord.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get some info from a table on my database using a discord command but I get an error saying that `results` is not defined and I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my code.

Here's the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

And here's my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { prefix, token } = require('../config.json');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, oldchars) => {

    const name = args[0];

    oldchars.query('SELECT * FROM characters WHERE name = ?', [name], function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) console.error(err);

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setThumbnail('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/wowwiki/images/1/19/Sylvanas-compact.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/180?cb=20150807220023')
    .setTitle('**Character Information**')
    .addField('Nickname:', results[0].name)
    .addField('Level:', results[0].level)
    .setFooter(`test`)

    .setTimestamp();


    message.channel.send(embed);
    });

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "charmaly",
}
```

Let me know if you need more information about the database.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you confirmed that the query that is actually being executed returns any results?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: For a start, I'd try it in a mysql command line.  But you could also do things like log what 'name' is being passed to the function for the query to make sure that is valid.